# psexec does not work properly when called from xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, jar, psexec, xp-cmdshell

I want to run a **jarfile** from an SQL Server to a different machine remotely. To do this, I found out I can use **PSEXEC** to send commands remotely to the target machine and use **xp_cmdshell** so I can call psexec command form a stored procedure.

I already extracted PSTools I downloaded from [technet website](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx). I copied PsExec.exe, PsExec64.exe and Eula.txt in C:\Windows folder of the SQL Server. I already tested it in the SQL Server's command prompt with the following command,

```
psexec \\mymachine -u mydomain\myuser -p mypassword cmd /c "java -jar C:\WriteToFile.jar"
```

WriteToFile_U4.jar writes to a text file in a shared folder. This shared folder is actually physically located in the SQL Server. Running the command above updates the text file. However, when I try to run WriteToFile_U4.jar thru xp_cmdshell with the code below the file does not get updated.

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'psexec \\mymachine -u mydomain\myuser -p mypassword cmd /c "java -jar C:\WriteToFile.jar"'
```

Also a weird output is displayed in the Results pane of SSMS.
[image]

I already added the **SQL Service Agent** in the folder security where WriteToFile_U4.jar updates a text file.

Does anyone know how to deal with this?
Does it matter in my issue that T-SQL commands I'm executing are executed as the SQL Service Agent? and not as the server Administrator account?

**UPDATE:**

I tried ditching the xp_cmdshell idea and just created an **SQL Server Agent job** whose type is **Operating System (CmdExec)**. The contents of the step is,

```
cmd.exe /c "D:\runjarfileremote.bat"
```

The contents of the bat file is,

```
psexec \\computer-name -u domain\user -p password cmd /c "hostname"
```

just to check if I can run psexec in an SQL Server Agent job. But the following is logged in the history of the job I created.
[image]

However, if I change the contents of the bat file to contain only `hostname`. The job finishes successfully. So I concluded that it is the psexec not really running properly when called as an SQL Server Agent job. Is there any way this can work? Or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

psexec (as with all current sysinternals tools) prompts on first run for any user for acceptance of a license. It may be being held up by that as it is being run by service accounts.

add -accepteula to the psexec command

example

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'psexec -accepteula \\mymachine -u mydomain\myuser -p mypassword cmd /c "java -jar C:\WriteToFile.jar"'
```